# Allow Azure AD Guest users to use app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

We have an application (SPA frontend using ADAL.js and Backend with passport bearer) that authenticates using Azure AD.

Logging in with users from our own AD works fine, and we can get information regarding these accounts via MS Graph.

I am however not able to log in using Guest accounts.
Some guest accounts are just stuck at the login screen (the azure ad account selector screen).

And some external users belonging to other tennants give an error message that the app was not found in their subscription.

Is this a configuration error?
The app manifest says that the app is not for other tennants.

As guest users are at least entries in the AD, I was assuming I could somehow log in using these accounts for our own AD and get access that way.

Maybe a vague question

[edit]

The error message our external users see:
(I assume this is a config error and the app tries to authenticate using their tennant?)

[image]

Comment: Usually, if all configuration is right, we can use guest users to login the application. But I'd like to  know more details about your error massage and configuration of the app.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the error. see above edit.
As for those getting stuck on the account selection screen, there is no error message, selecting your account just bounces against the microsoft login pages and back with no message.

I've also unchecked the "guest users have limited access" checkbox in Azure AD.

Comment: Try to go to Azure portal portal and edit the manifest of that application and set `availableToOtherTenants` flag to `true`.

Comment: Hi, Roger, may I know how is about your issue , do you have any process on it ?

Comment: Yes, I found the cause, I needed to pass the Tennant ID in the adal.js configuration, that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this here as an answer

> Yes, I found the cause, I needed to pass the Tennant ID in the adal.js
> configuration, that solved the issue

I was stuck in a similar issue where the users were stuck at the login screen.
I added the tenant id in adaljs configuration and that error got resolved.